# Xquery sum up partial DayTime durations

Tags: xquery

I have a problem with summing up durations using sum.

here is an example:

```
<total>
for $t in //Times
let $start_t := $t/@start
let $stop_t := $t/@stop
let $duration := xs:dateTime($stop_t) - xs:dateTime($start_t)
return
..... 
</total>
```

gives me a list of partial durations. How do I sum them up using sum?

thanks

Comment: You have to `accept` one of the answers -- this and upvoting, which you still lack the rep to do, are the accepted and encouraged practices to express gratitude at SO.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this XQuery/XPath expression:

```
sum(//Times/(xs:dateTime(@stop) - xs:dateTime(@start)))
```

Comment: Is there any way I can return a result as a variable and than for eg. display fn:days-from-duration, minutes, months... without repeating the query for each one?

Comment: @qba: Of course. You can use a [variable declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-variable-declarations) : `"declare" "variable" "$" QName TypeDeclaration? ((":=" ExprSingle) | "external")`

Comment: @qba: `let` clause would need a `return` as part of the FLWOR expression.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. I will nedd to do some more reading, it's somehow confusing with FLWOR and not FLWOR exp.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the whole query in a call to sum():

```
<total>
{
  sum(
    for $t in //Times
    let $start_t := $t/@start
    let $stop_t := $t/@stop
    return xs:dateTime($stop_t) - xs:dateTime($start_t)
  )
}
</total>
```

Comment: @Oliver-Hallam: Why should the OP use your answer and not @Alejandro 's? Please, comment.

Comment: @Dimitre:  My answer was illustrating the smallest required change to the OP's code to solve the problem.  @Alejandro further improved this by rewriting the FLWOR as a path expression.  I believe my answer still has value as rewriting with path syntax can be confusing for a novice XQuery user.  I too have upvoted Alejandros answer as it is a neater solution.